# Is a webpage loaded/rendered faster with HTML 4 transitional or HTML 5 DTD?

Tags: performance, html, dtd, html4

I have a webpage that is [HTML 4 transitional](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/loosedtd.html) and [HTML 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) compliant.  In the latest version of the browsers is there a performance gain (decrease in the time to load/render the page) if I code the page to use the HTML5 DTD (which means don't put a DTD) over the HTML 4 transitional DTD?

Comment: Why don't you try and benchmark it?

Comment: why rely on something which is just 1 line in the HTML for speed. optimize the HTML itself to get some speed.

Comment: A 1 line code change is easy to implement and in this case is low risk and I can scale it across multiple pages.  The page I was referencing was just an example. The company I am working for is looking at switching and I wanted to know the perf implications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`DTD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition) is just there to tell the browser (and a validator) what type of HTML you use and how your tags are deemed "valid".

> DTDs use a terse formal syntax that declares precisely which elements and references may appear where in the document of the particular type, and what the elements’ contents and attributes are.

A [`DOCTYPE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration) tells the browser what mode to use: strict or quirks mode which dictate how the browser should layout the page.

> The HTML layout engines in modern web browsers perform DOCTYPE "sniffing" or "switching", wherein the DOCTYPE in a document served as text/html determines a layout mode, such as "quirks mode" or "standards mode".

HTML5 has the doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` - **a DOCTYPE with no DTD**.

don't confuse them, they are different things.

There is no performance gain to it as far as i know. However, using a `DOCTYPE` makes a browser layout the page in a standards-compliant (and a more consistent, but not totally) way across browsers. This is a "handsomeness" benefit rather than speed.

> Since web browsers are implemented with special-purpose HTML parsers, rather than general-purpose DTD-based parsers, they don't use DTDs and will never access them even if a URL is provided. The DOCTYPE is retained in HTML5 as a "mostly useless, but required" header only to trigger "standards mode" in common browsers.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 parsing is 5% - 20% faster on Gecko

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/05/firefox-4-the-html5-parser-inline-svg-speed-and-more/

Comment: No, Gecko's new HTML5-compliant parser is faster than the old one, according to that article. But the new parser is used regardless of what the doctype is. There's no speed benefit to be gained by changing the doctype.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 doctype is several characters smaller than previous iterations which means fewer bytes and a smaller file size, which in theory would suggest that the HTML5 version has better performance.

**However**, I would suggest that if all you do is change the doctype, the performance gains will be minimal.